# Postgresql: query is aborting due to low tablespace despite provisioning high memory and space

Tags: postgresql

I am facing a strange bottleneck with Postgresql.
Earlier the DB was running on single core machine with 12GB RAM. We migrated it to a 8 core 64 GB RAM.
After this migration, many of the times it is creating huge temp files ~ 40GB, where as `pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('DB_name'));` is merely 1.9GB.

In the postgresql.conf

```
working_mem = 5GB
shared_buffer = 16 GB (25% of total RAM)
max_wal_size = 2GB
autovaccum = on
```

Despite the above configuration, I am getting the below msg:

```
'53100-could not write to file "pg_tblspc/226475/PG_11_201809051/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp13308.47": 
No space left on devicecould not write to file 
"pg_tblspc/226475/PG_11_201809051/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp13308.47
```

In fact I had changed the pg_tablespace from pg_default to a custom location using the below set of queries from `psql`.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE <tblspc_name> LOCATION </path/to/higher/disk/> OWNER postgres;
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> SET temp_tablespaces = tblspc_name;
GRANT ALL ON tblspc_name  to postgres;
```

I am not able to figure out what is missing here. What should be the approach to tackle this performance issue.

Comment: Study execution plans to figure out why temporary space is being used; they likely have changed due to query parallelism enabled by the multi-core CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of space in your default tablespace, because the query has to write so many temporary files. Perhaps you forgot a join condition or two, or you have infinite recursion somewhere.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I changed the default tablespace due to space issue. But it seems due to change in VM, this issue is occuring.

Comment: Oh, I see; you already set `temp_tablespaces`. So then you are running out of space there. I don't understand your comment: the error message makes clear that you are running out of space on the disk. This has no connection with virtualization.